# I want a query to select more than 4 AccountId repetitions from table2 having distinct name in table1

Tags: sql, select

I want a query to select more than 4 AccountId repetitions from table2 having distinct name in `table1`

Here are the table structures:

```
table1                             |       Table2
ID   AccountNumber  Name           |       ID       AccountNumber AccountID
1     12345         John Jeff      |        1          12345        A467T
1     12345         Patrick Jones  |        1          12345        A467T
```

`ID` and `AccountNumber` are the same on both tables

- Table1 has Name
- Table2 has AccountID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a query to find AccountID's with more than 4 different names:

```
select  t2.AccountID
from    Table1 as t1
join    Table2 as t2
on      t1.AccountNumber = t2.AccountNumber
        and t1.ID = t2.ID
group by
        t2.AccountID
having  count(distinct t1.Name) > 4
```

If that's not what you were looking for, please clarify the question!  For examole, you could add desired output.

EDIT: In reply to your comment, you could query the ID and Numbers with a subquery:

```
select  distinct 
        ID
,       AccountNumber
,       AccoutnID
from    Table2
where   AccountNumber in 
        (
        ... place query from above here ...
        )
```

Comment: Thanks Andomar it is working, but what if i want to have also AccountNumber and ID as part of the output

Comment: If there's only one AccountID per AccountNumber, you could `group by t2.AccountID, t2.AccountNumber, t2.ID` and select all three columns.

Comment: @Bayo Alen: then you'd have to go back to Table2 to figure out the ID's... one way is a subquery, example added.